# Adapting string in fortran

Tags: string, fortran

I have to a file to read and have fun with it. 
for exemple, I would like to have the delta T in it,
I use :

```
function GetDeltaT (whereabout) result (DeltaT)
    implicit none
    character(16)    , intent (in) :: whereabout 
    real(8)       :: CurrentTime
    Real(8):: DeltaT
    open(20,file=whereabout,status='old',action='read')
    read (20,*) DeltaT
    read (20,*) CurrentTime
    DeltaT=CurrentTime-DeltaT
    close(20)
    return
end function GetDeltaT
```

my problem is the definition of whereabout here : sometime I use 16 length title (as `AL026_pdcham.txt` for example)

But I can also use less. But when it is not 16 character long (`AL03_pdcham.txt` for example)
I have this warning message :

```
Warning: Character length of actual argument shorter than of dummy argument 'whereabout' (15/16)  |
```

and at the execution :

```
At line 46 of file C:\Users\LambourgA\Documents\stage\V1\ModularStructureRT V5\R
eadData.f90 (unit = 20, file = 'Ó3u')
Fortran runtime error: Invalid argument

Process returned 2 (0x2)   execution time : 0.042 s
Press any key to continue.
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: find here : http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap02/declare.html
I just have to declare it CHARACTER(LEN=*) and not character(16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
character(16)    , intent (in) :: whereabout
```

with

```
character(len=*), intent (in) :: whereabout
```

Now go back to your Fortran tutorial and learn about assumed type parameters.